# My server application is not responding to any requests

Tags: macos, xpc, cfsocket

I wrote a simple server which responds to http requests.
The server is based on CFSocket.
Everything works ok when the application runs standalone.

But now I rewrote it to a LaunchAgent app.
I use XPC to communicate with another process.

This communication between process works, but my server is not responding to connections on this socket.

The LaunchAgent plist looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>MachServices</key>
<dict>
<key>com.myApp.Server</key>
<true/>
</dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.myApp.Server</string>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true/>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
<string>Path/to/my/server.app</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

What am I missing?